# My navigation bar not showing dropdown when clicked

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to make my navbar `<a>` tag not clickable once on mobile view. I want it to be that when I click once it shows the drop down then when I click same link again it goes to the page

```
(function($) { // Begin jQuery
    $(function() { // DOM ready
      // If a link has a dropdown, add sub menu toggle.
      $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
        $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();

        // Close one dropdown when selecting another
        $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
        e.stopPropagation();
      });
      // Clicking away from dropdown will remove the dropdown class
      $('html').click(function() {
        $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
      });
      // Toggle open and close nav styles on click
      $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
        $('nav ul').slideToggle();
      });
      // Hamburger to X toggle
      $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
        this.classList.toggle('active');
      });
    }); // end DOM ready
  })(jQuery); // end jQuery
```

To be more clear, on desktop view if I hover the nav link it shows the dropdown. I can decide to enter the dropdown or click on the link itself the enter the page but on mobile there is no hover effect so whenever I click on the nav link it goes to the page without even showing the the drop down. I want it to be the one I click once it shows the dropdown then when I click on it again it goes to the page

Comment: Please describe what is not working the way you want.

Comment: @kmoser on desktop view if I hover the nav link it shows the dropdown. I can decide to enter the dropdown or click on the link itself the enter the page but on mobile there is no hover effect so whenever I click on the nav link it goes to the page without even showing the the drop down. I want it to be that when I click once it shows the dropdown then when I click on it again it goes to the page

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71896611/edit) to show the relevant HTML.